# Use variable inside fetch json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fetch

So i am working on a system to be able to get certain information from a json file via user input, But one issue i am having is that i do not know how to get a variable in the designated area;

```
        fetch(
          `here is a .json url`
        )
          .then((response) => response.json())
          .then((data) => {
            let returnInfo = data.(VARIABLE X HERE).name.toLocaleString();
            console.log(returnInfo)
           })
```

Now what i am trying to do is i want variable `X` to be inserted in the data fetch, But i have tried everything i could think of without being successful, If you know any way to make this work, Or even make this more efficient, I would love that!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can access it like: data[VARIABLE].name.toLocaleString(). and check javascript object here for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: @KetanRamteke - how is that at all relevant?

Answer (score -1):

`you can access it like: data[VARIABLE].name.toLocaleString(). and check javascript object here for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects – Hassan Ali Salem` 
This was the answer, Thank you @hassan ali salem!